# global array from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to create arrays based on the values of an ajax call and to able to use those arrays **outside** the ajax call (as global arrays).

This is my `books.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <book>
    <title>title1</title>
    <pages>100</pages>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>title2</title>
    <pages>200</pages>
  </book>
</root>
```

What I would like (set as global arrays):

```
title = array("title1","title2");
pages = array("100","200");
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `<pages>200</title>` should be `<pages>200</pages>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can globally declare a data object

```
var globalData = {
    title: [],
    pages: []
}
```

and in the ajax response handler function

```
function getData(data) {

    $(data).find("title").each(function(index, item) {
        globalData.title.push($(item).text());
    });
    $(data).find("pages").each(function(index, item) {
        globalData.pages.push($(item).text());
    });
    console.log(globalData.title, globalData.pages);

}
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/NdFDR/2/